# How can I test a trigger that generates primary keys?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

[image]

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EVALUATIONS_SEQ
  INCREMENT BY 1
  START WITH 1 ORDER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NEW_EVALUATION_TRIGGER
  BEFORE INSERT ON angajati
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    :NEW.id_angajat := evaluations_seq.NEXTVAL
  END;
```

how can i test this trigger?

[image]

Comment: My first thought:  Insert rows into the table and see if the primary key increments.

Comment: i tried this: insert into angajati(nume) values('marius');  and got this error : ORA-04098: trigger 'BDD23.NEW_EVALUATION_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? (`select * from v$version`)

Comment: hello, i am  using apex.oracle.com , the sql workshop.    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.3.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I write triggers to create auto-incremented values in Oracle, I use the syntax:

```
select evaluations_seq.NEXTVAL into :NEW.id_angajat from dual;
```

I haven't used a direct assignment.  Try this and see if it fixes the problem.

(I also express deep appreciation that they have finally put this functionality directly into the language, so triggers aren't needed in Oracle 12, just a `default` statement in `create table`.)

Comment: ORA-02290: check constraint (BDD23.ANG_EMAIL_NN) violated. got this error when i tried this: insert into angajati(nume,id_functie) values('marius','IT_PROG');

Comment: @mariusxd . . . (1) You shouldn't be doing this on a table that already has data in it.  (2) Edit your question and include the constraints on the table as well as the column definitions.

Comment: i added the constraints. i tried using another insert: insert into angajati(nume,email,id_functie,data_angajare,salariul) values('marius','dada','ff','06/17/1987',20000);.. and i got this error:ORA-02291: integrity constraint (BDD23.ANG_FUNCTIE_FK) violated - parent key not found

Comment: i guess its because that table had 2 primary keys i tried another table and it worked . thanks for all the answers though

Comment: @mariusxd No table can have 2 primary keys. I guess you meant a composite primary key, made of 2 columns.